# How to assert csv file content exists in laravel integration testing

Tags: php, laravel, csv, integration-testing

I am doing integration testing for a csv file download. I need to know is there a way to check the file content when running the test case?

Comment: how do you run the test?

Comment: Does the file already exist? Or are you generating it?

Comment: @Ross Wilson : I get a copy of generated file and store it Temp folder in project. file_exists() for that file returns true as well

Comment: @Nikhil Radadiya : I run test using terminal

Comment: Perhaps show your current code?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the content and check mandatory values via `asserContains` you also parse the csv file Into an array and use `assertArraySubset` or you completely process the file and check for a final result (DB rows, etc)

EDIT :

To read a file you can easier use the static method from `File`class : `File::get($filepath)` or directly through the file object : `$file->getContents()` if the last method doesn't work, just do as following :
`File::get($file->getRealPath())`

Comment: `File::get($file->getRealPath())` What is the location of this 'File'

Comment: You just need to retrieve the `UploadedFile` via `$file = $request->file('file_field')`

Comment: Request is called in the controller function and I am not calling it in Integrate testing class

Comment: You should though

Comment: In the integration test class I do not need Request yet

Comment: It's depends if your class takes an filename or à datastring as argument ^^